# Install Win 7 over XP on second hard disc drive

Tags: dual-boot

Before I get myself into serious trouble I thought I should ask some people who may know.  I have researched this but still think I will get into some troubles.  A few weeks ago I bit the bullet and switched to Ubuntu 12.04 and I must say I don't want to go back to Windows but I have an I-phone that I need to urgently unlock so I need I-tunes.  I installed WINE but couldn't get to to work.
I have a second hard disc drive from another PC on my computer with Windows XP on it but went about that the wrong way and due to that I of course cannot run Xp - gives a BSOD.  I have given in and bought WIN 7 and burnt the ISO file to disc.  I was going to unplug HDD1 that has UBUNTU on it and just load the CD and see if it will put WIN7 onto the HDD2 but I bet it is not that simple.  Can someone offer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but since Ubuntu and Windows are on separate drives with separate boot managers you won't see boot entries for both OSs in both managers. This means if you want to boot the OS on hard drive 2 you will have to enter your computers quickboot menu and tell it to boot from hard drive 2. Which for many people is the prefered way to do things. Keep in mind that some computer's quick boot menus don't allow selecting a specific hard drive to boot from, which would mean you would have to disconnect 1 drive to boot the other or fix the boot manager to list both Ubuntu and Window's bootloaders.

The best place to start would be to check your quick boot menu to see what the computer supports. For this test you should have both hard drives connected. This is done by pressing a specific key when the computer first turns on. The key varies by computer model, but it should say on the screen. Typical keys are F2, F4, F10, and F11. You should then get a list that says something along the lines of:

```
1. CD/DVD
2. Removable
3. Hard Drive 1
4. Hard Drive 2
5. Network
```

If you can pick between drives then your plan will work. Simply disconnect Ubuntu and install Windows then reconnect.

If it doesn't list a specific hard drive then you can't choose, and it will always try to boot from the first one to offer up a boot manager, which would prevent you from booting into 1 of the operating systems unless you disconnect the other drive. In this case you "may" be able to proceed by installing as planned and then running a program called boot-repair from Ubuntu when both hard drives are connected. This should add an entry for Windows to the Ubuntu drive.

Alternatively you can install VirtualBox on Ubuntu and install Windows 7 in a virtual machine. Then re-direct the usb device to the virtual machine so that Windows 7 can interact with it.

Comment: The GRUB boot manager currently lets me choose Ubuntu (default) or WIN XP on HDD2 but WIN XP won't run because the HDD is from another machine and of course Windows cannot deal with that.  So I want to put WIN 7 on the second HDD.  Do I need to wipe HDD2 first?

Comment: You can wipe it first or you can wipe it from the Windows 7 installation disc before it installs. Alternatively you can use Ubuntu to shrink the XP partition and then install Windows 7 beside XP. XP still won't boot, but that way you don't have to delete it if you are planning to fix XP at some point.